# What are the limits of manual reclustering of a table in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's say that I have a table (with **no automatic reclustering**) that is not specially well-clustered:

```
create or replace table recluster_test3  
(
    id NUMBER
    ,value NUMBER
    ,value_str VARCHAR
)
cluster by (value)
;
alter table recluster_test3 suspend recluster; -- no automatic reclustering
describe table recluster_test3;

insert into recluster_test3  (
 select seq4() as id
         ,uniform(1,20, random()) as value
         ,randstr(10000,random()) as value_str
 FROM TABLE(GENERATOR(ROWCOUNT => 500000)) 
);
show tables like 'recluster_test%';
```

the clustering info for this newly created table:

```
select system$clustering_information('recluster_test3');
{
  "average_depth": 367,
  "average_overlaps": 366,
  "cluster_by_keys": "LINEAR(VALUE)",
  "partition_depth_histogram": {
    "00000": 0,
...
    "00512": 367
  },
  "total_constant_partition_count": 0,
  "total_partition_count": 367
}
```

I can manually r[ecluster the table](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tables-clustering-manual.html) with

```
create or replace table recluster_test4 clone recluster_test3;
alter table recluster_test4 suspend recluster; -- no automatic reclustering
alter table recluster_test4 recluster; -- recluster manually,
select system$clustering_information('recluster_test4');
{
  "cluster_by_keys" : "LINEAR(VALUE)",
  "total_partition_count" : 394,
  "total_constant_partition_count" : 376,
  "average_overlaps" : 1.7778,
  "average_depth" : 2.0,
  "partition_depth_histogram" : {
    "00000" : 0,
    "00001" : 376,
    "00002" : 18,
    "00003" : 0,
...
  }
}
```

This reclustering is not complete (it's possible to get to `"00001": 367`). Is there any way to force a more complete reclustering?

Although in this case the reclustering was pretty good, in a real dataset with 190TB and 400000M rows each recluster does not fundamentally improve the clustering depth.

So the real question is

- what are the limits of `alter table xxx recluster`? I believe that there are hard limits on how much data can be recluster in one go and how much time it's spent on each recluster.

Note: Automatic reclustering is disabled due to cost concerns (data is continuously added to the table) and automatic reclustering was consuming lots of snowflake credits.

Answer (score 0):

There are limits on how much will be reclustered for every run however the exact numbers are not shared by Snowflake - I ***guess*** it is based on:

- the size of the virtual warehouse
- the size of your table
- the clustering stats on the table

Manual reclustering is being deprecated so it might be a good idea to contact Snowflake support first about this, you may find that you go down a route that will not be supported in the future.

Also when you run the `alter table <table> recluster` command I believe you can provide a predicate which would limit the amount of data reclustered (like a date?) or `MAX_SIZE = <budget_in_bytes>`